# Speeding up Win10 IoT Core boot time

Tags: windows, iot, raspberry-pi3

I'm trying to speed up Win10 IoTCore's boot time. Currently it sits at something around 40s, which is very slow imo. Every Video or post regarding this situation I have found is either from 2015, when it came out or not related to my problem.
Has anybody succeeded in maybe stripping it of some functions (like Cortana) so that it would boot quicker?
I'm on a Raspberry Pi 3 using Win10 IoTCore Build 10.0.15063.0.
I also tried building my own image (as described here https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/hardware/commercialize/manufacture/iot/set-up-your-pc-to-customize-iot-core), but to no avail.

Comment: Have your tried disable Cortana on boot time? You can enter `http://<device IP>:8080/#Device%20Settings` into a browser, scroll to the bottom and un-check “Start Cortana on Boot”.

Comment: Yes Cortana is disabled already. Still it takes about 50s to boot (From plugging in power to Standard IoT App being available). Any other ideas?

Comment: You can set the device to headless mode to stop the IoTCoreDefaultApp to start.  And use [official recommended cards](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/Docs/hardwarecompatlist#Storage) for better performance.

Comment: I am currently using the Raspi-Card from Farnell (http://de.farnell.com/transcend/tsraspi10-16g/16gb-microsd-card-preloaded-with/dp/2521753), which is from Transcend, so that may cause a problem. I'll replace it with the Samsung Card and try again.
Since I want to use an App with a GUI, headless mode is not an option. I uninstalled the IoTCoreDefaultApp and set my own Test App (one button, one edit field and one text view) as startup application, so that shouldn't take too long by itself.
I'll get back as soon as I tried out the other card.

Comment: For custom image, you can try the following edits: 1# [Don't use compression to improve device performance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/commercialize/manufacture/index); 2# [Tailor features](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/commercialize/manufacture/iot/iot-core-feature-list).

Comment: Thank you all for your input. For the time being we decided not to go in the WIn10 IoT direction anymore, since it seemed more feasible to use an embedded Linux for what we're trying to achieve.

Comment: For those still digging into this... it's really more a problem with SD read performance. Linux is likely to be a bit better here, but if you are trying to product-ize raspberry pi, I'd reocmmend engineering emmc storage into it.

Comment: Wow you get 40 seconds!!?? I never get better than 60 with a samsung evo sd card... What is your card?